# Checking the monotonicity of radical function

Tags: real-analysis

I am in stuck with the following difficult problem:

Using definition (without using derivative), checking the monotonicity of 
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^4+1}{\sqrt[3]{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x-1}}
$$
over the interval $(2,+\infty)$.
Thank you for all solutions.

Comment: I have tried to use definition but I cannot.

Comment: Multiplying numerator and denominator by $a^2 - ab + b^2$ where $a = \sqrt[3]{x+1}$ and $b = \sqrt[3]{x-1}$ gives $\frac{1}{2}(x^4 + 1)(a^2 - ab + b^2),$ which can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{2}(x^4 + 1)(A + \sqrt[3]{x^2 - 1}),$ where $A = \left(\sqrt[3]{x+1} - \sqrt[3]{x-1}\right)^2.$ Since $x^4 + 1$ and $\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}$ each are increasing for $x > 0$ (for instance, $x^2$ is increasing for $x>0,$ and hence $x^2-1$ is increasing for $x>0,$ and hence $\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}$ is increasing for $x>0),$ it suffices to show that $A$ is increasing for $x>2.$ However, I don't know how to show this for $A.$

Comment: $A$ is not increasing.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=\frac{4x^3(\sqrt[3]{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x-1})-\left(\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}}+\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}}\right)(x^4+1)}{\left(\sqrt[3]{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x-1}\right)^2}=$$
$$=\tfrac{12x^3\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2(x-1)^2}\left(\sqrt[3]{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x-1}\right)-(x^4+1)\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}\right)}{3\left(\sqrt[3]{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x-1}\right)\sqrt[3]{(x^2-1)^2}}=$$
$$=\tfrac{12x^3\left((x-1)\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+(x+1)\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}\right)-(x^4+1)\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}\right)}{3\left(\sqrt[3]{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x-1}\right)\sqrt[3]{(x^2-1)^2}}>$$
$$>\tfrac{12x^4\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}\right)-12x^3\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}\right)-(x^4+1)\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}\right)}{3\left(\sqrt[3]{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x-1}\right)\sqrt[3]{(x^2-1)^2}}=$$
$$=\tfrac{(11x^4-12x^3-1)\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}\right)}{3\left(\sqrt[3]{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x-1}\right)\sqrt[3]{(x^2-1)^2}}>0$$
for all $x\geq2.$

I tried to prove that
$$\frac{x^4+1}{\sqrt[3]{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x-1}}>\frac{y^4+1}{\sqrt[3]{y+1}+\sqrt[3]{y-1}}$$ for all $x>y\geq2$  and I think if it's possible during reasonable time then it's very very ugly.

Comment: The OP asked for a solution which does NOT involve derivatives.

Comment: I think it's impossible!