# Is there a way to show monotonicity of this function without using a derivative?

Tags: inequality

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476952/checking-the-monotonicity-of-radical-function/2477338#2477338) question, I was wondering if there is any way to show the following inequality without using derivatives?

$$ x(\sqrt[n]{x+1}-\sqrt[n]{x-1}) - y(\sqrt[n]{y+1}-\sqrt[n]{y-1}) \geq 0 $$
for all real $x>y>2$ and for some $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq2}$ (if a proof is possible for a specific $n$, feel free to pick one).

**EDIT:**
I am most interested in the case where $n=3$.

Just by plotting the function $f(x) = x(\sqrt[n]{x+1}-\sqrt[n]{x-1})$, one already sees that the assertion as given is wrong for $n\geq 7$, since then $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing between $[2,2+\delta]$, $\delta >0$.

Also, $x^\alpha(\sqrt[n]{x+1}-\sqrt[n]{x-1})$ is monotonically decreasing for all $\alpha < 1-1/n$ and $x>0$, as can be shown using Newton's binomial expansion (one might argue this is worse than using derivatives, but well): 
$$ x^\alpha(\sqrt[n]{x+1}-\sqrt[n]{x-1}) - y^\alpha(\sqrt[n]{y+1}-\sqrt[n]{y-1}) \leq 0 $$
$$\Leftrightarrow \sum_{l=0}^\infty {{1/n}\choose{l}} \left[1+(-1)^{l+1}\right] \left( x^{\alpha+1/n-l}-y^{\alpha+1/n-l}\right) \leq 0 $$
 If $\alpha+1/n-l<0$ for all $l\geq 0$, then this is true. Unfortunately, this proof does not work so easily in the monotonically increasing case.